# Changing the httpd location file

Tags: apache, centos

I want to change httpd log location on **centos**
the location where is install dont have a good memory 
so i want to move it to **/home/httpdlog/**
Thanks for any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "ErrorLog" and "CustomLog" directive (in httpd.conf file) and change the directory

please check this link :

```
https://serverfault.com/questions/875697/changing-apache-2-4-xs-log-files-directory-on-centos-7
```